# changing behaviour of expression in jsp to escape xml and html special characters

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

If i have `<c:set var="str" value="This <mytag>is a tag.</abc>"/>`
now if i print it using as `<p>tag  : ${str}</p>` will produce result

```
"This is a tag."  i want to print it as "This <mytag>is a tag.</abc>"
```

for that i can use `<c:out value="${str}" />`. 
But i need this without `<c:out />` or `${fn:escapeXml(str)}`. 
Can i change behaviour of expression language to do that?

Comment: Can you escape manually? Just use &lt;  and use  &gt;

Comment: @rickz The problem is that i have huge project with lot of jsp's  now i don't want to do this change everywhere.

Comment: If you look at the source code that your server is sending to your browser, then you will see that your JSP is doing what you want it to do. The browser just doesn't display the tags because it sees them as unknown HTML tags.    Maybe you can use your IDE to do the substitutions through out your web app.